# Append a row to a pair RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a pair RDD of existing values such as :
(1,2)
(3,4)
(5,6)

I want to append a row (7,8) to the same RDD

How can I append to the same RDD in Spark?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use union operation.

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6)))
q: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List((7, 8)))
q: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val unionOfTwo = rdd1.union(rdd2)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = UnionRDD[2] at union at <console>:28
```